# (Validation) to Post only one record in a minute in MVC Post

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Im doing **post Action** through **MVC Form Post**, I need some validation sort in C# that **allows only one record** to be posted in a minute.. not more than that. I have a date property called 'CreatedWhen' which stores the date of the current record. So how do i check the same ?

Comment: That's kind a typical requirement though you can disable the form post for a minute duration from the last post. But this won't work on a distributed architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable for Save button in your form like this.

In controller Post method with `GET` action

```
ActionResult Post(){
    var latest = context.Post.OrderByDesc(x=>x.CreatedWhen).FirstOrDefault();
    var disable = (DateTime.Now - latest.CreatedWhen).Seconds < 60;
    if(disable){
        ViewBag.Disable = true;
    }
}
```

In view

```
<button type="submit" @(ViewBag.Disable ? "disabled" : "")>Post</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 'CreatedWhen' record is in the database, then something like:

```
void PostRecord(...)
{
    var existingRecord = _dbContext.TableName.OrderBy(x=>x.CreatedWhen).LastOrDefault();

    if (existingRecord!=null && existingRecord.CreatedWhen <= DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    {
       ... save record
    }
}
```